# Insert Image to database using typescript (angular2) and spring boot (spring data)

Tags: rest, file-upload, angular, spring-boot, spring-data

I start by presenting my client side the service

```
    addImage (url: string, params: string[], files: File[]): Observable {
                return Observable.create(observer => {
                    let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
                        xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], file

s[i].name);
                }

                xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                            observer.complete();
                        } else {
                            observer.error(xhr.response);
                        }
                    }
                };

                xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
                    this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

                    this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
                };

                xhr.open('POST', url, true);
                xhr.send(formData);
            });

    }
```

then this is my html code

```
<input type="file" (change)="uploadImage($event)"/>
```

where I call this method from my component

```
uploadImage(event) {
        var files = event.srcElement.files;
        console.log(files);
        this._serviceSection.addImage('http://localhost:8080/template/img', [], files).subscribe(() => {
            console.log('sent');
        });
    }
```

and in my service side

this is a method from my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/img", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void getFileContents(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ " +file.getOriginalFilename());
    }
```

in a first time a try just to show a fileName but I get this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `progressObserver` isn't set. The reason for this could be that you didn't subscribe to its associated observable. Don't forget that observables are lazy and if you don't subscribe to them, their initialization callback isn't called.

To prevent from having the error, you could check if it's null or not:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
  if (this.progressObserver) {
    this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

    this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
  }
};
```

Otherwise, you can notice that from RC2, Angular2 accepts `FormData` objects as parameters of HTTP methods...

Comment: how can we get the onprogress callback using the Http service method while we are uploading and using a FormData as a body ?